# Generate Normal Inverse Gaussian (NIG) distributed random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, moment-generating-functions

For an $NIG(\alpha, \beta, \mu, \delta)$ distributed random variable $X$, it is established (see e.g. [here](http://public.econ.duke.edu/%7Eget/browse/courses/883/Spr15/COURSE-MATERIALS/Z_Papers/BNS2012.pdf))) that $X$ can be constructed as a normal mean-variance mixture of a Gaussian random variable $U\sim N(0,1)$ subordinated by an Inverse Gaussian distributed random variable $Z\sim IG(\delta,\gamma)$ with a scaled and shifted version of $Z$,
\begin{equation} 
X = \mu + \beta Z + \sqrt{Z} U, 
\end{equation}
where $\alpha = \sqrt{\beta^2 + \gamma^2}$, the IG density $f_Z$ of $Z$ is given by
\begin{eqnarray} 
f_Z(z) &=& \frac{\delta}{\sqrt{2\pi z^3}} e^{\delta\gamma} \exp\left[-\frac{1}{2} (\delta^2/z + \gamma^2 z) \right] \\ 
&=& \frac{\delta}{\sqrt{2\pi z^3}} \exp\left[-\frac{1}{2z} (\gamma z -\delta)^2 \right] \; 
\end{eqnarray}
and we have $\sqrt{Z} U \sim N(0,Z)$ due to the properties of the normal distribution.

The density $f_X$ of the $NIG(\alpha, \beta, \mu, \delta)$ distribution is then given by
\begin{equation}
f_X(x) = \frac{\alpha \delta}{\pi}\exp\left[ \delta \sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2}-\beta\mu \right] \,  \frac{K_1(\alpha \sqrt{\delta^2 + (x-\mu)^2} )}{\sqrt{\delta^2 + (x-\mu)^2}},
\end{equation}
where $K_1$ is the modified Bessel function of the third kind.

I found a claim that $X$ can also be constructed as $X_1$ by using $Z_1$ distributed $IG(1,b)$ with
\begin{equation} 
b = \delta \sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2} \,
\end{equation}
setting
\begin{equation}
X_1 = \mu + \beta \delta^2 Z_1 + \delta \sqrt{Z_1} U \; ;
\end{equation}
then $X_1$ would also have a $NIG(\alpha, \beta, \mu, \delta)$ distribution.

I do not see how this claim can be proven (e.g. from the above). Is it due to a different parametrization?
I tried to compute the Laplace exponent $L_{X_1}(u)= \log \mathbb{E}\left[e^{u{X_1}}\right]$ of ${X_1}$ and compare it with $L_X$ of $X$; the latter has been shown to be
\begin{equation}
L_X(u) = \log \mathbb{E}\left[e^{uX}\right] = \delta \left( \sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2} - \sqrt{\alpha^2 - (\beta+u)^2} \right) + \mu u \; ;
\end{equation}
then I compute $L_{X_1}$, e.g. via splitting $X_1$ into $A = \mu +\beta  \delta^2 Z_1$ and $B = \delta \sqrt{Z_1} U$ and using
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\left[e^{u{X_1}}\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[e^{uA} e^{uB} \right] = \mathbb{E}\left[e^{uA}\right]  e^{L_{Z_1}(\phi(u;0,\delta^2))} \;,
\end{equation}
where $L_{Z_1}(u) = L_{IG}(u;1,b)$ with $L_{IG}(u;a,c)$ the Laplace exponent of an $IG(a,c)$-distributed random variable,
\begin{equation}
L_{IG}(u;a,c) = a ( c - \sqrt{c^2-2u}) \;,
\end{equation}
and $\phi(u;m,s^2)$ being the moment generating function of the normal distribution with mean $m$ and variance $s^2$,
\begin{equation}
\phi(u;m,s^2) = m u + \frac{1}{2} s^2 u^2 \; ;
\end{equation}
however I get conflicting results, containing $1/\delta$ in the front of $L_{
X_1}$ for example.

What is missing or wrong? I would be grateful for any help. Thanks in advance!